# Remove inconsistent duplicate entries from data frame with Base R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove duplicate entries from a data frame that are inconsistent, the following gives a simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Andy", "Bert", "Cindy", "Cindy", "David", "Edgar", "Edgar", "Frank", "George", "George", "George", "Herbert", "Iris", "Iris", "Iris"), amount = c(100, 50, 30, 30, 200, 65, 55, 90, 120, 120, 120, 300, 15, 25, 25))
df
##       name amount
## 1     Andy    100
## 2     Bert     50
## 3    Cindy     30
## 4    Cindy     30
## 5    David    200
## 6    Edgar     65
## 7    Edgar     55
## 8    Frank     90
## 9   George    120
## 10  George    120
## 11  George    120
## 12 Herbert    300
## 13    Iris     15
## 14    Iris     25
## 15    Iris     25
```

**Version A)**
Edgar and Iris are the same person yet the given amounts are inconsistent so I want to remove the entries:

```
#remove inconsistent duplicate entries
df2
##       name amount
## 1     Andy    100
## 2     Bert     50
## 3    Cindy     30
## 4    Cindy     30
## 5    David    200
## 6    Frank     90
## 7   George    120
## 8   George    120
## 9   George    120
## 10 Herbert    300
```

**Version B)**
Another possibility would be to keep only one instance of the consistent entries:

```
#keep only one instance of consistent entries
df3
##      name amount
## 1    Andy    100
## 2    Bert     50
## 3   Cindy     30
## 4   David    200
## 5   Frank     90
## 6  George    120
## 7 Herbert    300
```

I am interested in (elegant?) ways to solve both versions in Base R. Efficiency should not be a problem because the dataset I have is not that huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)** First `aggregate` to apply the conditions, then filter the data and finally `stack` the result.

```
t <- aggregate( amount ~ name, df, function(x) c(unique(x),length(x)) )

t_m <- t[!sapply( t$amount, function(x) (length(x)>2) ),]

setNames( stack( setNames(lapply( t_m$amount, function(x) 
  rep(x[1],x[2]) ), t_m$name) )[,c("ind", "values")], colnames(df) ) 
      name amount
1     Andy    100
2     Bert     50
3    Cindy     30
4    Cindy     30
5    David    200
6    Frank     90
7   George    120
8   George    120
9   George    120
10 Herbert    300
```

**B)** Is a bit more straightforward. Just `aggregate` and filter.

```
t <- aggregate( amount ~ name, df, unique )

t[lengths(t$amount) == 1,]
     name amount
1    Andy    100
2    Bert     50
3   Cindy     30
4   David    200
6   Frank     90
7  George    120
8 Herbert    300
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. Is there the possibility of also putting out more columns of larger data frames with your second solution using aggregate?

Comment: @vonjd Yes, basically unlimited. You can group/combine the first part to which the functions is applied to and also the group by section.

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution that solves both at once. This has the side effect of requiring row name changes.

**A** Remove "inconsistent" values

```
  new_df<-do.call("rbind",
            Filter(function(x) all(x$amount == x$amount[1]),
                    split(df,df$name)))

            name amount
Andy         Andy    100
Bert         Bert     50
Cindy.3     Cindy     30
Cindy.4     Cindy     30
David       David    200
Frank       Frank     90
George.9   George    120
George.10  George    120
George.11  George    120
Herbert   Herbert    300
```

The above needs further cleaning of row names (an unwanted side effect perhaps but we deal with that below)

**B** Remove duplicates

```
 new_df<-new_df[!duplicated(new_df$name),]
 row.names(new_df) <- 1:nrow(new_df)
```

Combined result

```
new_df
         name amount
    1    Andy    100
    2    Bert     50
    3   Cindy     30
    4   David    200
    5   Frank     90
    6  George    120
    7 Herbert    300
```

The question **specifically** requests for a `base` solution. If for whatever reason someone from the future wants to use `dplyr`, I will leave this solution here.

Using `dplyr`, we can check if all values are equal to the first value of amount. If not, make them `NA` and delete them. Proceed with removing duplicates for what remains.

**A** Remove inconsistent ones

```
library(dplyr)
(df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
   mutate(name = ifelse(!all(amount==first(amount)), NA, name)) %>% 
   na.omit()  -> new_df)

 A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   name [7]
   name    amount
   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Andy       100
 2 Bert        50
 3 Cindy       30
 4 Cindy       30
 5 David      200
 6 Frank       90
 7 George     120
 8 George     120
 9 George     120
10 Herbert    300
```

Remove duplicates

```
new_df %>%
   filter(!duplicated(name)) %>% 
   ungroup()
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  name    amount
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 Andy       100
2 Bert        50
3 Cindy       30
4 David      200
5 Frank       90
6 George     120
7 Herbert    300
```

Comment: Thank you but you only solved the second version.

Comment: It solves both at once. I have broken up the code into sections @vonjd

Comment: you can avoid the row name creation by either calling `Reduce` instead of `do.call`, or by using `unname(split(etc))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `duplicate`, but you need to remove all duplicate rows. (your option B).

The result can be used to filter the data frame for all rows.

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c("Andy", "Bert", "Cindy", "Cindy", "David", "Edgar", "Edgar", "Frank", "George", "George", "George", "Herbert", "Iris", "Iris", "Iris"), amount = c(100, 50, 30, 30, 200, 65, 55, 90, 120, 120, 120, 300, 15, 25, 25))

df_unq <- unique(df)
df3 <- df_unq[!(duplicated(df_unq$name)|duplicated(df_unq$name, fromLast = TRUE)), ]

df3
#>       name amount
#> 1     Andy    100
#> 2     Bert     50
#> 3    Cindy     30
#> 5    David    200
#> 8    Frank     90
#> 9   George    120
#> 12 Herbert    300

df[df$name %in% df3$name, ]
#>       name amount
#> 1     Andy    100
#> 2     Bert     50
#> 3    Cindy     30
#> 4    Cindy     30
#> 5    David    200
#> 8    Frank     90
#> 9   George    120
#> 10  George    120
#> 11  George    120
#> 12 Herbert    300
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For the first requirement, where you need to get rid of duplicate entries, there's an in-built function in R called `duplicated`.

Here's the code:

```
df[!duplicated(df), ]
df[!duplicated(df$name),]
```

The output looks like this:

```
      name amount
1     Andy    100
2     Bert     50
3    Cindy     30
5    David    200
6    Edgar     65
8    Frank     90
9   George    120
12 Herbert    300
13    Iris     15
```

And for the second requirement, you'll need to do something like this:

```
df <- unique(df)
df <- split(df, df$name)

df <- df[sapply(df, nrow) == 1]
df <- do.call(rbind, df)
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
```

The output looks like this:

```
     name amount
1    Andy    100
2    Bert     50
3   Cindy     30
4   David    200
5   Frank     90
6  George    120
7 Herbert    300
```

Both versions are using Base-R. You can do the same using `dplyr` package in R.

Comment: Thank you but in your first version Edgar and Iris are still present.

Comment: I've changed the code now to satisfy the condition!

Comment: Your first table and mine are completely different, please compare them and you will see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem **B** is a *sub-problem* of problem **A**. To solve **A** we can use `var()` to find *inconsistent* values, utilizing the behavior of `Filter()` which always takes `NA`s as `FALSE`. To solve **B** we just need to get rid of duplicated rows in **A** applying `unique()`.

##### Case A

```
with(df, df[!name %in% names(Filter(var, split(amount, name))), ])

#       name amount
# 1     Andy    100
# 2     Bert     50
# 3    Cindy     30
# 4    Cindy     30
# 5    David    200
# 8    Frank     90
# 9   George    120
# 10  George    120
# 11  George    120
# 12 Herbert    300
```

##### Case B

```
with(df, df[!name %in% names(Filter(var, split(amount, name))), ]) |>
    unique()

#       name amount
# 1     Andy    100
# 2     Bert     50
# 3    Cindy     30
# 5    David    200
# 8    Frank     90
# 9   George    120
# 12 Herbert    300
```